# How to convert array of chars to array of ints?

Tags: c++, c, string, array, convert

I have a rather newbie question but I can't figure it out.

Lets say I have this char array:

```
char array[] = "10,11,12,1,0,1,0";
```

How can I convert it to an array of int like this?

```
int arrayINT[] = {10,11,12,1,0,1,0};
```

Comment: Are you sure those arrays contain what you want them to? In the first case, are you looking for an array which contains the values 10, 11, 12, 1, 0, 1 and 0?  (That's not what you have -- you have a string containing an ASCII 1, an ASCII 0, an ASCII comma, and so on.) And the second one I'm almost certain isn't what you want - it's an array of pointers to very short strings (if the compiler even allows it).

Comment: yes i know, i'm building http server and this is a part of a string that i recieve from my web page

Comment: OK. Do you want it to end up as `int arrayINT[] = { 10, 11, 12, 1, 0, 1, 0 }` ?

Comment: Yes, it seems that Majenko's answer below is working properly :)

Comment: I'll edit your question then, so it asks what you want.

Comment: Yes of course :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a C string containing ASCII numbers with a common delimiter (comma in this case) you can use the `strtok()` function to split it into individual strings.  Then you can use `atoi()` to convert those individual strings into integers:

```
char array[] = "10,11,12,1,0,1,0";
int intArray[7]; // or more if you want some extra room? 

int ipos = 0;
// Get the first token from the string
char *tok = strtok(array, ",");
// Keep going until we run out of tokens
while (tok) {
    // Don't overflow your target array
    if (ipos < 7) {
        // Convert to integer and store it
        intArray[ipos++] = atoi(tok);
    }
    // Get the next token from the string - note the use of NULL
    // instead of the string in this case - that tells it to carry
    // on from where it left off.
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

Note that `strtok()` is a *destructive* function. It will decimate your existing string with NULL characters as it slices it up.

Comment: Amazing, this is working. I knew about strtok() and atoi() but couldn't get them working properly. Thanks very much!!

Comment: A major improvement would be counting the commas in the string and allocating an array of the approriate size. On the other hand, why not convert the nth value at runtime?